# How to have multiple values for each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So let's I have a table with these values

| Name | Transportation |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | air |
| Sarah | car |
| Trevor | air |
| Carl | car |

I'd like each person to use each transportation mode so an outcome as such

| Name | Transportation |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | air |
| Mike | car |
| Sarah | air |
| Sarah | car |
| Trevor | air |
| Trevor | car |
| Carl | air |
| Carl | car |

I tried creating a list then exploding the values but I was having issues adding a list as column values. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([{'Name': n, 'Transportation':df.Transportation.unique()} for n in df.Name]).explode('Transportation')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': n, 'Transportation':df.Transportation.unique()} for n in df.Name]).explode('Transportation', ignore_index=True)
```

OR:

```
df = df.assign(Transportation = df['Transportation'].apply(lambda x:df.Transportation.unique())).explode('Transportation', ignore_index=True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     Name Transportation
0    Mike            air
1    Mike            car
2   Sarah            air
3   Sarah            car
4  Trevor            air
5  Trevor            car
6    Carl            air
7    Carl            car
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
out = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Name.unique(),df.Transportation.unique()]).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
out.columns = df.columns
Out[161]: 
        0    1
0    Mike  air
1    Mike  car
2   Sarah  air
3   Sarah  car
4  Trevor  air
5  Trevor  car
6    Carl  air
7    Carl  car
```

Comment: How about passing df.columns as `names` to MultiIndex.from_product? `out = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Name.unique(),df.Transportation.unique()], names=df.columns).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be `df.get` then unique then form a `Multiindex.from_product`:

```
cols = ['Name','Transportation']
comb = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(map(pd.unique,map(df.get,df[cols])))
out = pd.DataFrame(comb.to_list(),columns=cols)

 print(out)

         Name Transportation
    0    Mike            air
    1    Mike            car
    2   Sarah            air
    3   Sarah            car
    4  Trevor            air
    5  Trevor            car
    6    Carl            air
    7    Carl            car
```

Or with levels on an index:

```
cols = ['Name','Transportation']
comb = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[cols]).levels)
out = pd.DataFrame(comb.to_list(),columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

for

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'Transportaion': ['t1', 't2', 't1', 't2']           
})
```

that is:

```
    Name    Transportaion
0   a       t1
1   b       t2
2   c       t1
3   d       t2
```

This code:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'Name': t[0], 'Transportation': t[1]} for t in itertools.product(df['Name'].unique(), df['Transportaion'].unique())])
```

returns:

```
    Name    Transportation
0   a       t1
1   a       t2
2   b       t1
3   b       t2
4   c       t1
5   c       t2
6   d       t1
7   d       t2
```